# Converting a shell script to a dmg

Tags: shell, ksh, dmg

I have a shell script with some functionalities. I want to convert it to an executable file. Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line at the very top of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This is known as a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). It indicates which program to invoke the shell script with when you execute it. You could change it to anything. Eg, to run a zsh script you would use #!/bin/zsh, which is the path to the zsh interpreter on my machine.

Then you need to mark the file as executable using [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod). You can do this as follows:

```
chmod +x myscript
```

You can now run the script like this:

```
/full/path/to/myscript
```

Or, if you're in the directory the script is in:

```
./myscript
```

The '.' expands to the path of your current working directory.

If you want to be able to run the script from anywhere, stick it somewhere in your [path](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs541/unix_path.html). Eg.

```
mv myscript /usr/bin
```

You can now run the script from anywhere by typing in just the name.

Comment: can we make it as an app?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mark it as executable & move it to /usr/bin, you'll be able to use it like you do any other app on your machine.